# Segmantation fault in c++, no output

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a C++ program to read input from a file ,put spaces before delimiters,and write to another file.
Example:
Input: 
int main()
Output:
int main ( )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

fstream oup, inp;
int dsize = 18;
char delim[] = {',',  ' ', '\n', '\t', '\"', '(', ')', '{', '}',
                '\'', '[', ']',  '+',  '-',  '*', '&', '/', '%'};

bool isDelim(char c) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
    if (c == delim[i])
      return true;
  return false;
}

void chartost(string a) {
  int d = 0;
  if (a.length() == 1)
    oup << a << " ";
  else {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
      if (isDelim(a[i])) {
        d = 1;
        oup << a.substr(0, i) << " ";
        chartost(a.substr(i, a.length()));
      }
    }
    if (d == 0) {
      oup << a << " ";
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  cout << "Initial Point";
  inp.open("test.c", ios::in);
  oup.open("testspace.c", ios::out);
  string a;
  cout << "before isopen";
  if (inp.is_open() && oup.is_open()) {
    while (inp >> a) {
      cout << a;
      chartost(a);
    }
    cout << "after operations \n";
    inp.close();
    oup.close();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

To debug I've used cout at many places. 
I'm getting a segmentation fault for this and even the cout at the entry point of main is not being displayed.

Comment: Try running in a debugger to catch the crash in action. That will help you locate where in your code the crash happens, and also let you examine the values of involved variables.

Comment: Also to guarantee you `cout` statements are displayed put a `endl` statement after the output.

Comment: Codeblocks -warning:GDB:Failed to set controlling terminal:Operation not permitted

Comment: That is why i posted the question here. Now it'd really kind of you if you could just look into the code or try it instead of downvoting the question.

Comment: @AnkitVimal No one can try your code since it reads from a file we don't have.  Also, please fix the formatting.

Comment: I would start with fixing the coding style. The indentation is awful.

Comment: Try the given input .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is a mess which makes it very hard to spot errors, however I notice that your chartost function is recursive but does not terminate when the recursion exits.  The for loop for the first call will process the rest of the string *after* the code has recursed on the rest of the string.  I would start off looking for your problem in there.

Comment: thanks..i'll start looking into it

Comment: the problem was in the construction of the substring,the length of the substring was wrong and hence the program was trying to construct a string of 0 length. Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: you probably want to exit the loop after the recursion call anyhow (or remove the recursion and just use the loop instead)... but I'm glad you found the immediate problem!